# Export multi-length list to excel in R

Tags: r, list, export-to-excel

I'm a beginner and have searched throught the repository of I'm looking to export the result of the following code into xlsx. Could you help me?

```
y<-seq(1980,1987,1)
Out <- apply(expand.grid(y),1,function(x){
i<-"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bollywood_films_of"
j<-paste(i,x[1],sep="_")
url<-j

# extract all tables on the page
tabs = readHTMLTable(url, stringsAsFactors = F)

# locate tables containing call and put information
top_10 = tabs[[2]]
Allmov  = tabs[[3]]

Topgenre = merge(top_10,Allmov,by.x="Title",by.y="Title")
year<-paste(x[1],"Rank",sep="")
myvars = c("Title",year,"Genre")
Top = Topgenre[,myvars]
Top[,2]<-x[1]
data = Top

rm(Allmov,Topgenre,top_10,i,j,year,myvars,tabs,url)

return(data)
})
```

Thanks,
Vijay

Comment: Read the help for `write.table` or `write.csv`. Then you can open the file these create in excel.

Comment: The Output, a list is of varying length. I've tried, write.table or write.csv, but it didn't work for me. Could you send me the exact code please

Answer (score 1):

You could create a different `.csv` file for each element of the list with `write.csv`. Then the files can be read into an Excel spreadsheet easily.

```
> lapply(seq(Out), function(i){  
      write.csv(Out[[i]], file = paste0("Out", i, ".csv"), row.names = FALSE)
  })
```

**If you want the entire list sent to a single file:**

```
> file.create("myfile.txt")
> lapply(seq(Out), function(i){
      capture.output(print(Out[[i]]), file = "myfile.txt", append = TRUE)
  })
```

If your actual list is very long, you may want to wrap either of these calls with `invisible()` to suppress the `lapply` output.

**A side note:**  You have a couple of lines of code that are unnecessary. For instance, `url<-j` and `data = Top` really aren't doing much.  Also, instead of `Topgenre[,myvars]`, you can just put the undefined vector inside the `[]`, `Topgenre[, c("Title",year,"Genre")]`, since you don't use it again in this code.

Just a thought.

Comment: But i want all of it in a sheet appended one below the other.

Comment: Keep in mind you'll want to create the file anew somewhere in that code, otherwise if you rerun you'll just keep appending without ever starting over.